# How to make progress bar with real percent number with Promise and Async/await with Just native javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have something i searched a lot about the solution but i don't find anything. Also i tried a lot of things but also no thing work with me. I hope to find something here.

I build a website, in some stages i allow the user to convert his images from any type to WEBP. So I made I constructor function to do this proccess:

```
async function loadImage(url) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', e => resolve(img));
        img.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error(`Failed to load image's URL: ${url}`));
        });

        img.src = url;
    });
}

async function convert(image, options) {
    let newImage = new Image();
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

        // convert canvas to webp image
        newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL(`image/${options.to}`, 1);
        resolve(newImage)
    });
}

async function Converter(userImage, options) {

    let src = URL.createObjectURL(userImage);

    let image = new Image();

    image.src = src;
    image.style.width = "auto";
    image.style.height = "auto";

    let t;

    await loadImage(src).then(img => {
        return convert(img, options)
    }).then(newImage => {
        t = newImage;
    })

    return t;
}

export default Converter;
```

I allow him to load the images and converting it with Javascript without upload the images to server.

I am using this function in another js file like this:

```
        formInputs.addEventListener('change', e => {

                if (formInputs.files.length > 0) {
                    updateFilatorTable(filatorInput.files);
                }
            })
```

As you see i am using promises and async/wait, for waiting images to load and convert. but the problem also here in await. how can i show the user Progress bar when the image loading and after that showing another progress bar when the image converting, with real percent for example: 25% converting.

Every thing working good but the problem is how to show progress bar when i load the image and when i convert it?

can i make something like that with promise and await?

Comment: `convert` is not actually asynchronous. No reason to use promises here.

Comment: @Bergi How is that?! when i am not using promises the images not coming really, and how can i use progress bar here?

Comment: You haven't actually shown us the `updateFilatorTable` function or anything related to a progress bar

Comment: My comment was specifically targeted at the synchronous `convert`. The `loadImage` and `Converter` functions you have still need promises; `async`/`await` is fine in there.

Comment: `.then(newImage => {  t = newImage; })` doesn't make much sense. This really should be just `const img = await loadImage(src); const t = await convert(img, options); return t;`

Comment: @Bergi Yeah i show you the loadImage function and convert function where my images loading and converting. See it in the first code the first Functions.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your answer to improve the code. i wanna change it, but what about the progress bar.

Comment: What progress do you want to show? There is no `progress` event on images, only the `load` one. Are you trying to load multiple images and count them?

Comment: @Bergi I am trying to add progress but i need to get The percent number like 25% Converting when the convert function start work and when loadImage function start work that is. Yeah i know i don't add it yet but where should i add it and how to handle the number like 25%

Comment: As I wrote, `convert` is synchronous, so at that point it's already at 100% (have you measured how long its execution is actually taking?). And no, there is nothing where you could get a number like 25% from.

Comment: So in this case should I guess how the convert will take?
so i should make a fake progress bar for this one>? @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi how r u? you don't answer me. "should I guess how the convert will take? Or 
I should make a fake progress bar for this one?"

Comment: Again, did you measure how much time the `convert()` call usually takes?

Comment: @Bergi  No, because it varies according to the image size. Ok if i measure it what should i make after that

Comment: So how long does it take? 5ms? 50ms? 500ms?

Comment: @Bergi it take 40sec

Comment: @Bergi i am sorry it take 40ms not sec

Comment: Yes, about what I would've guessed. You won't need a progress bar for that a short time anyway. And in fact you *cannot* update (animate) a progress bar while JS is processing synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi ok thank you I got it. Do you have any other idea to load images and convert it to allow real progress bar

Comment: @Bergi Give me Answer on this question to give you green mark and close this question